# Images not sent to inbox, using PHP mail()

Tags: php, email

I have an online property submission area in my website which lets users send properties in the form of text with images, to my email address:

But I'm not receiving the images. I only receive the text. I am trying to figure out why this is happening, but I couldn't find out anything that would cause this. Can someone help me find out the issue?

**Code:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['propertystatus'])) {
  // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
  $email_to              = "contact@scale-property.com";
  $email_subject         = "New Property From Customer";
  $email_subject_to_user = "Copy of your email";
  $propery_Information   = 'PROPERTY INFORMATION';
  $propery_Location      = 'PROPERTY LOCATION';
  $contact_Information   = 'CONTACT INFORMATION';
  function died($error)
  {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were errors found with the form you submitted.<br>";
    echo $error . "<br />";
    die();
  }
  // validation expected data exists
  if (!isset($_POST['propertystatus']) || !isset($_POST['currencytype']) || !isset($_POST['currency']) || !isset($_POST['rooms']) || !isset($_POST['bathroom']) || !isset($_POST['kitchen']) || !isset($_POST['yard']) || !isset($_POST['housedesproperty']) || !isset($_POST['drop_1']) || !isset($_POST['drop_2']) || !isset($_POST['drop_3']) || !isset($_POST['region']) || !isset($_POST['street']) || !isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['emailadd']) || !isset($_POST['conemailadd']) || !isset($_POST['phone1']) || !isset($_POST['phone2']) || !isset($_FILES['uploadimages'])) {
    died('You have not properly selected the fields.');
  }
  // start code of attachement
  if (empty($_FILES['uploadimages']['name'])) {
    echo 'You have\'nt Entered Value for upload field';
    exit();
  } else {
    $attachment      = $_FILES['uploadimages']['tmp_name'];
    $attachment_name = $_FILES['uploadimages']['name'];
    if (is_uploaded_file($attachment)) {
      $fp   = fopen($attachment, "rb");
      $data = fread($fp, filesize($attachment));
      $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
      fclose($fp);
    }
    $headers = "From: $email<$email>\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: <$email>\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/related; type=\"multipart/alternative\"; boundary=\"----=MIME_BOUNDRY_main_message\"\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP4\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: <$email>\n";
    $headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";
    $headers .= "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_main_message \n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"----=MIME_BOUNDRY_message_parts\"\n";
    $message = "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_message_parts\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n";
    $message .= "\n";
    $message .= "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_message_parts--\n";
    $message .= "\n";
    $message .= "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_main_message\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n\tname=\"" . $attachment_name . "\"\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n\tfilename=\"" . $attachment_name . "\"\n\n";
    $message .= $data; //The base64 encoded message
    $message .= "\n";
    $message .= "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_main_message--\n";
    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
  }
  // end   code of attachment
  $property_status  = $_POST['propertystatus']; // required
  $currency_type    = $_POST['currencytype']; // required
  $currency         = $_POST['currency']; // required
  $rooms            = $_POST['rooms']; // required
  $bathroom         = $_POST['bathroom']; // required
  $kitchen          = $_POST['kitchen']; // required
  $yard             = $_POST['yard']; // required
  $housedesproperty = $_POST['housedesproperty']; // required
  $drop_1           = $_POST['drop_1']; // required
  $drop_2           = $_POST['drop_2']; // required
  $drop_3           = $_POST['drop_3']; // required
  $region           = $_POST['region']; // required
  $street           = $_POST['street']; // required
  $name             = $_POST['name']; // required
  $emailadd         = $_POST['emailadd']; // required
  $conemailadd      = $_POST['conemailadd']; // required
  $phone1           = $_POST['phone1']; // required
  $phone2           = $_POST['phone2']; // required
  $error_message    = "";
  $email_exp        = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if (!preg_match($email_exp, $emailadd) && !preg_match($email_exp, $conemailadd)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  $email_message = "Property details below.\n\n";
  function clean_string($string)
  {
    $bad = array(
      "content-type",
      "bcc:",
      "to:",
      "cc:",
      "href"
    );
    return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
  }
  $email_message .= "" . clean_string($propery_Information) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "--------------------------------------------" . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Property Status: " . clean_string($property_status) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Total Price: " . clean_string($currency_type) . " " . (number_format($currency, 2, '.', ',')) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Rooms: " . clean_string($rooms) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Bathrooms: " . clean_string($bathroom) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Bathrooms: " . clean_string($kitchen) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Bathrooms: " . clean_string($yard) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Description: " . clean_string($housedesproperty) . "\n\n";
  $email_message .= "" . clean_string($propery_Location) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "--------------------------------------------" . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Province: " . clean_string($drop_1) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "District: " . clean_string($drop_2) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "PD(Nahya): " . clean_string($drop_3) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Bathrooms: " . clean_string($region) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Street: " . clean_string($street) . "\n\n";
  $email_message .= "" . clean_string($contact_Information) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "--------------------------------------------" . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Email ID: " . clean_string($emailadd) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Con-Email ID: " . clean_string($conemailadd) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Phone(1): " . clean_string($phone1) . "\n";
  $email_message .= "Phone(2): " . clean_string($phone2) . "\n";
  // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: ' . $emailadd . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $emailadd . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
  @mail($emailadd, $email_subject_to_user, $email_message, "From: $email_to");
?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Your Property has been Posted please check your email address.



<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,this for multiple image attachment

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/07/22/sending-email-with-multiple-attachments-with-php/

Comment: To improve your answer you could "quote the most relevant part of an important link". You can see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more details